# Swift Key Values from Dictionary without brackets

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to print/assign key/value data in Swift, brackets surrounding the data. I want to hide/cut the brackets.

Have tested in Swift with Code below.

```
func listenForChanges() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Block").document("Test")
            .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
                guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                    print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                guard let data = document.data()?.values else {
                    print("Document data was empty.")
                    return
                }

                self.syncText.text = "\(data)"
        }
}
```

Current result is -> [value]

Expected result should be -> value

Any suggestion to hide the brackets?

Comment: Read the docs / try to understand what the type of `data` is and fo from there! https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRDocumentSnapshot(im)data

Comment: i would presume that `document.data()?.values` returns an array, which would also explain  `[value]`. if your data is returning a single value in an array try `print(data.first)`

Comment: document.data()? is a dictionary and .values are only values without the key

Answer (score 0):

As @Scriptable suggested it works with the following:

```
self.syncText.text = "\(data.first!)"
```

Thank you!